# Convert NSArray to NSstring in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsarray

i have a NSMutableArray called delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish from application delegate, it have some values, i am able to get the array count and i can show it correctly in UITableView. But now i want to display it in a textview. My UITableView code is like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    readCell *cell = (readCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"readCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0]; 

        cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
        cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:19.0];
    }
}
```

It shows correct values in the cell, but i just need to show this delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish array in a textview, like `textview.text = delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish;`. How it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how you want the text to be formatted.
For logging purposes, I'd use `[delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish description];` while for showing it to the user something like `[delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];` might be suitable.

Comment: thanks for the reply,,so i have to write textview.text =[delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]; right?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10359/question-10266190

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this -

```
NSString *stringToShow = nil;
for (NSString *stringObj in delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish) {
    stringToShow = [stringToShow stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringObj]];
}
cell.textLabel.text = stringToShow;
```

Comment: Why don't yo use `stringObj` instead of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringObj]`?

Comment: as per question it is not clear that array contains always string variables?But if we are sure then we can definitely use this :)

Comment: Why do you use `for (NSString *stringObj in ..` then?

Comment: @RIP i put NSString *stringToShow = nil;
for (NSString *stringObj in delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish) {
    stringToShow = [stringToShow stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringObj]];
}
cell.textLabel.text = stringToShow; agin no result..the array contains text in it